# Best approach to separate and re-factor a large number of dependent classes

Tags: .net, refactoring, code-reuse, dto

I have a v-large number of hierarchical structures (or DTO's) that are shared across different business logic, application tiers, web service and WCF contracts. I want to refactor all of my code to split the structures into discreet business domain areas.

Two questions:

1. Are there any tools that can help me do this (given that I want class A, list all of the dependencies)?
2. Is there a case for duplicating DTO's in different application domains to allow them to evolve independently? The idea of a fixed Canonical Business Model is pure fiction!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding number 2: 
sure, bounded context:  http://dddcommunity.org/discussion/messageboardarchive/BoundedContext.html
check this post to understand it better: http://devlicio.us/blogs/casey/archive/2009/02/11/ddd-bounded-contexts.aspx

For number 1 Resharper :)

Answer (score 1):

Resharper/CodeRush can help with question# 1. They both have good support for refactoring.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/code_refactoring.html#Rename

Answer (score 1):

I'll start with [NDepend](http://www.ndepend.com/) analysis to list dependencies (see this article : [Control Component Dependencies to gain cleaner architecture](http://www.theserverside.net/tt/articles/showarticle.tss?id=ControllingDependencies))

And then I'll use Resharper to ease the refactoring.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Structure 101 (not free)(www.structure101.com/) and/or Code Navigator (free) (http://plugins.intellij.net/plugin/?id=3202) might be useful